# HTML codes are displayed in App instead of the formatted type of html in xcode

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode7

My app is showing html codes in the screens. we use txt file which contains html code. on browser it is proper and in app showing the code in txt file.

Comment: what you have tried ,and what you are trying us to ask ...explain clearly

Comment: Provide info on what platform you're trying and which framework you're using.

Comment: I'm so sorry that im not clear on the topic. im using a third party app for my company. so on certain pages there are data present which is accessed from a txt file in a format of html. before it was showing in an ordered format now the complete HTML code is visible after updating ios9 i guess

Comment: they used objective c i guess and the s/w is build for version 7

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the content in a textView than You can try this.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourFileName" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                  initWithData: [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                       options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
            documentAttributes: nil
                         error: nil
        ];
        textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```